# Is it possible to use @Issue annotations to impact the category a test appears as inside an Allure report?

Tags: allure

Is it possible to use `@Issue` annotations to impact the category a test appears as inside an Allure report?

I would like tests with an `@Issue` annotation to show in "Product Defects" and those without to appear in "Test Defects".

[image]

```
@Issue("JIRA-1234")
public void productDefect() {
    // Test which fails and should be categorised as product defect
}
```

The Allure documentation on [categories](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_categories_2) doesn't show a way of doing this. Is there a way of controlling the category based on on the issue annotation or is is exclusively the test error message/stack trace?

If this isn't possible out of the box, is there a workaround to easily achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to currently be possible, but there is an open request for the feature on [GitHub](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/issues/685).